# how to open date picker in jquery mobile (with hide keyboad)

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile .I need to show date picker on clicking the text field,along with i need to hide keyboad on clicking the date text field. As a default  functionality keyboard is open when user click textfield keyboard is open but i need to only open date picker on clicking the text field..Here is code.

```
 <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;" >Date:</label>
                            <input name="text-12" id="documentCaseDate" value="" type="text">
                        </div>
```

Comment: yes i need date box but i don't see any code ?can you write some code?

Comment: Actually i Google a lot but  not able to use ..

Comment: Please tell me how to add datepicker ?

Answer (score 1):

If required to have a **Datepicker in jquery mobile** why not have a use of [Jquery Mobile Datebox](https://github.com/jtsage/jquery-mobile-datebox)...

It is a **Date UI for jquery mobile framework**, has got of other features like...

- Multiple Data-Entry Modes
- 4 Different display modes
- Fully localized
- Supports data-limiting of input
- Automatically parses hand-entered or pre-entered dates on open
- Auto-bind's to data-type='datebox', options are configurable via data-options.

Full Plugin can be download from [Jquery Mobile Datebox](https://github.com/jtsage/jquery-mobile-datebox) and homepage could be refered as [Jquery Mobile Datebox Homepage](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/)....

Thanks...